# How to handle asynchronous sendMessage calls?

Tags: ios, sendmessage, watchos, watchconnectivity

My app communicates with its companion app (iOS or watchOS) using `sendMessage(message:replyHandler:errorHandler:)`.

My understanding is that after calling this function, one has to wait until it is finished, i.e. until either `replyHandler` or `errorHandler` is called, before `sendMessage` can be called again.

In my case, `sendMessage` can be called by multiple asynchronous events. Thus, the calls have to be queued while an ongoing `sendMessage` has not been finished yet, and the oldest call each has to be dequeued when a `sendMessage` finishes.

I can imagine to set up a class storing the function parameters (`message`, `replyHandler` and `errorHandler`) as properties, and to define a fifo queue with such objects as elements, so that every time `replyHandler` or `errorHandler` is called, an object is dequeued and executed as `sendMessage`.

However, this seems a bit awkward to me. Is there an easier way to handle the problem?

**EDIT:**

Maybe such queueing is done automatically by WatchKit? I cannot find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run several test that called `sendMessage(message:replyHandler:errorHandler:)` before `replyHandler` was called, and everything worked correctly, i.e. when I stopped sending messages, the remaining replyHandlers were called.
So obviously `sendMessage` calls are queued internally, and one does not have to care about it.